# JES2 SPOOL volume waiting for jobs, but $DJ shows no jobs

Tags: zos

I’m trying to drain a JES2 SPOOL volume. It says it’s waiting for jobs:

```
$DSPL
$HASP893 VOLUME(SPLZ00) 852
$HASP893 VOLUME(SPLZ00)  STATUS=DRAINING,AWAITING(JOBS),
$HASP893                 PERCENT=2
$HASP893 VOLUME(SPLZ01)  STATUS=ACTIVE,PERCENT=38
$HASP893 VOLUME(SPLZ02)  STATUS=ACTIVE,PERCENT=36
$HASP646 37.5371 PERCENT SPOOL UTILIZATION
```

But when I look to see which jobs it’s waiting for, I don’t find any:

```
$DJ(*),SPL=(VOL=SPLZ00)
$HASP003 RC=(52),D 879
$HASP003 RC=(52),D J(*)  - NO SELECTABLE ENTRIES FOUND MATCHING
$HASP003           SPECIFICATION
```

Any ideas about why this volume won’t finish draining?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dave Gibney on the IBM-MAIN mailing list (IBM-MAIN@LISTSERV.UA.EDU), I have the answer.

$DJ doesn't show started tasks or TSO users. $DJQ(*),SPL=(VOL=SPLZ00) displays everything. There's also $DS that just shows STC and $DT that only show TSU.

Answer (score 0):

Though $DJQ commands show batch jobs, TSO users and Started tasks, but it does not include job group logging jobs.  You would need to use the command $DG(*),SPL=(VOL=SPLZ00) to show any job groups using a spool volume.